# OData expanded not nullable property filtered out by the DB throws "The property '{0}[Nullable=False]' of type '{1}' has a null value..."

Tags: odata, webapi, expand, row-level-security, notnull

I have an OData WebApi application that uses EF6 DB first. RLS has been introduced to the database on some tables and data can be filtered out.
When expanding on such an entity, if the data is filtered out by the database and in the selected fields there are not nullable properties of the filtered entity, the following error occurs "The property '{0}[Nullable=False]' of type '{1}' has a null value, which is not allowed"
Is there any way to allow null values in such cases?

Just modifying the metadata in the builder does not work because I still want the property to not be nullable when trying to add new data or modify existing data.
Omitting the Metadata validation makes the problem go away but this disables much more than null checks and I think it is risky to do so.